# Do Yoda or Darth Vader speak Huttese?

Tags: star-wars, languages

I'm curious if these two extremely notable *Star Wars* characters can speak Huttese. Would a conversation with Jabba be possible? Has this been shown?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the new direction of the series, so haven't watched the new cartoons, but I'm pretty sure Anakin and Obi-Wan have a conversation with Jabba in the *Clone Wars* series. Someone less annoyed with George Lucas will probably have mor einfo for you.

Comment: Anakin speaks Huttese in the prequel movies, iirc. He grew up in Tattooine after all, and Hutteese is a major language there.

Comment: @Shisa: He speaks Toydarian, not Huttese. I wouldn't be slightly surprised if Anakin does speak it, though. It's established in the *EU* that Luke Skywalker can read Jawa, and Owen Lars clearly understands the spoken version of that language in *A New Hope*. Any major language on Tatooine is likely to be at least understood by its lower-class residents; it's more like an old seaport than a modern city.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Watto and Ani are speaking Huttese, the primary language of Hutt-controlled Tatooine, not Toydarian. (Scroll down for script from the Insider guide) http://www.completewermosguide.com/hutttranscript.html

Comment: @Shisa: Is there anything official on that? It certainly doesn't sound Huttese to my ear, though it looks a lot moreso on the page.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html) says "Huttese".  Is that official enough?

Comment: @DarthSatan: The script? Of course not! I will accept nothing less than a signed affidavit from George Lucas itself. The signature, of course, must be written in George's own blood.

Answer (score 18):

Let's ask [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html):

> INT. WATTO'S JUNK SHOP - DAY
>
> WATTO and ANAKIN are in the middle of an animated discussion **in Huttese**.
>
> WATTO : Patta go bolla!
> ANAKIN : No batta!
> WATTO : Pedunky. Maa kee cheelya.
> ANAKIN : Bayno, Bayno!

That's a "yes" for Anakin then, but I'm not aware of any evidence in the movies for Yoda.

Comment: That's Anakin talking, not Darth Vader!

Comment: Ummmmmm..... what?

Comment: So you're telling me that Anakin and Darth are the same person??? But that means that Darth Vader is Luke's father! 

Comment: NEVERRRRRRRRRRR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Richard: No! That's not true! That's impossible!

Comment: @JamesSheridan Search your feelings, you know it to be true!

Comment: @RyanJ: No! No.

Answer (score 5):

### Vader

Vader certainly spoke Huttese back when he was a child, as detailed in [this answer.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68592/51379) This is also borne out in the novelization of *The Phantom Menace*, which, though no longer fully canon, does provide further confirmation that Anakin and Watto were speaking Huttese in that scene:

> “Patta go bolla!” he shouted in Huttese, chubby body jerking with the
>   force of his words.
>
> The boy blinked, but held his ground. “No batta!”
>
> “Peedunkel!” Watto flitted backward and forward, up and down,
>   everything moving at once.
>
> <sub>*The Phantom Menace*</sub>

As such, a conversation between Vader and Jabba would not only be possible, but *has in fact happened* (in the *Darth Vader* comic series):

[image]

The angular braces around Jabba’s dialogue indicates that he is speaking in Huttese. Vader shows no difficulty understanding it, but (judging from the lack of braces around his dialogue) is conversing in Galactic Basic. **Thus we see that *Vader*, as opposed to Anakin, still understands Huttese, and has not forgotten it since he was a child.**

I suspect that Huttese has negative associations for him, seeing as it was the language spoken when he was a slave in Hutt-controlled territory. Speaking Basic may also be a way of asserting his power—he is not obligated to speak Jabba’s language. Of course, this sort of mutual passive bilingualism is the norm in *Star Wars*, so perhaps it requires no explanation.

### Yoda

We have no evidence that Yoda speaks Huttese. However, he has been alive for nine hundred years in a highly multilingual galaxy, and Huttese is a common trade language. It seems likely that he at least understands Huttese, and possibly speak it.